# SwiftUI View is reinitialized when @Binding Property has not been modified

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding, viewmodel

I am executing a SwiftUI playground that contains 2 labels and 2 buttons that modified the value of these labels.

I've stored the value of these labels in a `@ObservableObject`. Whene I modify the value of any of these properties, **both** views `CustomText2` and `CustomText3` are reinitialized, even the one that his values has not changed.

Code:

```swift
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var title: Int
    @Published var title2: Int

    init(title: Int = 0, title2: Int = 0) {
        self.title = title
        self.title2 = title2
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(
                action: {
                    viewModel.title += 1
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            )
            CustomText1(
                    title: $viewModel.title
                )
            Button(
                action: {
                    viewModel.title2 += 1
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            )
            CustomText2(
                title: $viewModel.title2
            )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CustomText1: View {

    @Binding var title: Int

    init(
        title: Binding<Int>
    ) {
        self._title = title
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(title)")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

However if I store both properties as `@State` in the view and I modify them, the `CustomTexts` are not reinitialized, they just update their value in the body without executing an init.

Why are they getting reinitialized when I store both properties in the `ViewModel`?

I've tried to make the views conforming Equatable but they're reinitialized.
Can be a performance problem if the views are initialized many times?

I am interested in not having the subviews reinitialized because I want to perform custom stuff in the init of some subviews.

Comment: "I am interested in not having the subviews reinitialized because I want to perform custom stuff in the init of some subviews.". This is a mistake and will introduce fragility. Even if you addressed your current issue it is likely that the views may be recreated for other reasons; light/dark mode switch or device rotation or...  SwiftUI views are ephemeral.

Comment: This is known, You should never do work in the `init` of a SwiftUI `View` SwiftUI can initialize and update views whenever it wants. The `StateObject` is meant to be consistent, do any work there. It is bad practice to do work in a SwiftUI `View`

Comment: As others have said, you should not care how many times a SwiftUI struct is (re)initialized. Structs are cheap to create/destroy, this is one of the reasons they were chosen for the SwiftUI framework. If you have unwanted side effects due to this, you might want to re-structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

@ObservableObject is for model data, not view data.

The reason is when using lets or @State vars, SwiftUI uses dependency tracking to decide if body needs to be called and in your case body doesn't use the values anywhere so there is no need to call it.

It can't track objects in the same way, if there is a @StateObject declared then body is called regardless if any properties are accessed, so it's best to start with @State value types and only change to @StateObject when you really need features of a reference type. Not very often now we have .task which is the place to put your custom async work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have one **StateObject** that encompasses multiple State variables, change in one will redraw the entire view. In your case, any change in any variable in *viewModel* will trigger the publisher of *viewModel* and reload *ContentView*

Also we are not supposed to make any assumptions on when a View will be redrawn, as this might change with different versions of SwiftUI. Its better to move this custom stuff you are doing in the init of views to some other place(if it can be). Init should only do work needed to redraw the view with the new state parameters and nothing else.